# I can't fix this error (Selenium) [stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document ]

Tags: python, selenium

I'm currently trying to scrape a website to get the price of a 3d printer but I'm constantly running into this error.
This is the code:

```
    import selenium
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://www.dx.com/p/creality-cr10-v2-upgrade-ultraquiet-twoway-sphenoid-cooling-3d-printer-eu-plug-2711457.html#.Xy6c1SgzZhE')  
    price = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('low-sale-price')
    p = price
    if not p:
        print('Printer out of stock')        
    if price != "":
        for val in price:
            a = val.text
            b = str(a)
            print(b)
            break
```

And this is the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\scham\Desktop\PrinterCrawler.py", line 117, in <module>
 DealExtremeEnder()
 File "C:\Users\scham\Desktop\PrinterCrawler.py", line 111, in DealExtremeEnder
 c = post.text
 File "C:\Users\scham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
 packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 76, in text
 return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
 File "C:\Users\scham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
 packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
 return self._parent.execute(command, params)
 File "C:\Users\scham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
 packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
 self.error_handler.check_response(response)
 File "C:\Users\scham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
 packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
 selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element 
 is not attached to the page document
 (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.105)
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This worked for me: https://pastebin.com/8sp2SEyW. I used the Firefox web driver instead of Chrome, and did `from selenium import webdriver` instead of just `import selenium`. One thing I suspect is that there is a popup when you visit the website, and that might be messing with the availability of a certain element.

Comment: @igor The error _StaleElementReferenceException_ isn't originating from this code block but from the line `c = post.text` which you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that looping through elements in `price` is causing the `StaleElementReferenceException` - this means an element in the `price` list has changed in the DOM, and will require you to call `driver.find_elements` once again in order to "refresh" the elements with non-stale references.

You could try modifying your code as such to re-find the list of elements in `price`:

```
    import selenium
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://www.dx.com/p/creality-cr10-v2-upgrade-ultraquiet-twoway-sphenoid-cooling-3d-printer-eu-plug-2711457.html#.Xy6c1SgzZhE')  
    price = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('low-sale-price')
    p = price
    if not p:
        print('Printer out of stock')        
    if price != "":
        for val in price:
            a = val.text
            b = str(a)
            print(b)
            
            # refresh price element list before re-iterating the loop
            price = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('low-sale-price')

            break
```